# Postfix php mail issue "CLIENT: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed"

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, centos7, postfix-mta

Im trying to configure postfix to send smtp emails using phpmailer on centos 7 hosted on **Azure virtual machine**. (Firewalld/selinux disabled already)

My problem is i get **'CLIENT: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled SMTP ERROR'** when I try to use **phpmailer**.

```
2018-06-02 16:07:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 myserver.com ESMTP Postfix 2018-06-02 16:07:17    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO myserver.com 2018-06-02 16:07:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-myserver.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 10240000 250-VRFY 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN 2018-06-02 16:07:17  CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2018-06-02 16:07:17    SERVER -> CLIENT: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled 2018-06-02 16:07:17   SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled 2018-06-02 16:07:17    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2018-06-02 16:07:17  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 2018-06-02 16:07:17 SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

This is my phpmailser mail settings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>PHPMailer - SMTP email test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$host = "localhost";
$username = "captan@myserver.com";
$password = "XUF9?YMd";
$Port = 25;

$mail->FromName = "Mail from rovo ";
$mail->From = "captan@myserver.com";
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->Port = $Port;
#$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; //optional 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;


$mail->AddAddress("mymail@yahoo.com");
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer - SMTP email test';
$mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

i **cant use phpmailer** due to above error but I **can** **successfully telnet** to port 25 withing the server

```
[root@myserver ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 myserver.com ESMTP Postfix
```

**postconf -M** results like this

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
465        inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
587        inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
25         inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

postconf -n results

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples myhostname = myserver.com mydomain = myserver.com myorigin = win home_mailbox = mail/ mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 inet_interfaces = all inet_protocols = all inet_interfaces = localhost mydestination = myserver.com, localhost.com, localhost, com smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth smtpd_sasl_local_domain = smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination smtp_tls_security_level = may smtpd_tls_security_level = may smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1 smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.key smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.crt smtpd_tls_received_header = yes smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Please guide me to fix the issue. googling and Troubleshooting over several hours yet no clue.

Answer (score 2):

Most servers don't allow authentication without encryption, and you've not configured that - the server is not advertising any AUTH mechanisms, so PHPMailer is just giving it a try.

It's also normal to not allow sending on port 25, which is why the SMTP submission protocol exists; submit using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` on port 587, or with `ssl` on port 465.

Alternatively, since it's localhost, why bother authenticating at all? Try `$mail->SMTPAuth = false;`

Comment: thanks for you advise. I tried both options .. yet looks like my issue is something else..

Comment: but you gave me a great hint.. "Most servers don't allow authentication" may be that is the issue ..ITs azure vm https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresecurity/2016/08/16/pro-tip-on-sending-email-from-azure-virtual-machines-to-external-domains/

Comment: I have wasted lot more time.. it should be the reason " we do *not* allow you to send email to external domains from Azure (this includes email servers and applications that send email as part of the service they provide).

To solve this problem, you’ll need to use an SMTP relay that is *not* hosted in Azure. That SMTP relay can be on-premises or you can use an SMTP hoster. Whatever works best for you."